# How do I make myself device administrator?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I can't disable, uninstall, or uncheck `phone info` as device administrator. Why?

Answer (score 1):

In [this thread](https://community.norton.com/t5/Other-Mobile-Products/Norton-Halt-exploit-gt-hidden-device-administrator-gt-phone-info/td-p/1070249), the poster was unable to find the cause, but was advised by Samsung to factory reset. According to the thread, `phone info` appears to be a hidden app with many permissions, perhaps malware.